# Spark Submit: You have not specified a krb5.conf file locally or via a ConfigMap

Tags: apache-spark, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm using to spark-submit directly to submit a Spark application to a Kubernetes cluster. using the below command :

#### Submit Spark

```
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://localhost:8443  
--deploy-mode cluster  --name spark-pi 
--class com.xxx.Main 
--conf spark.executor.instances=5  
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:latest 
local:///home/SparkJob_jar spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/opt/xxx
```

But I'm getting the below exception:

```
20/09/25 11:33:57 WARN Utils: Your hostname, XXXX resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using xxx.yyy.zzz instead (on interface wlp59s0)
20/09/25 11:33:57 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/09/25 11:33:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/09/25 11:33:58 INFO SparkKubernetesClientFactory: Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file
20/09/25 11:33:58 INFO KerberosConfDriverFeatureStep: You have not specified a krb5.conf file locally or via a ConfigMap. Make sure that you have the krb5.conf locally on the driver image.
20/09/25 11:33:58 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Exec Failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
```

The post https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31800 suggested adding *spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path* to solve the problem, I added it to the submit command, but the issue still there. I appreciate any help to figure out the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you might havae to add the following configuration flags to make the certificats available

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.oauthTokenFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token  \
```